# How to get values in new column, instead of new row?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to make iReport subreport do something like:

> a b c

but it returns me:

> a
>
> b
>
> c

How can I make that every new value goes into new column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you use `columnCount` and `printOrder` on the `jasperReport` tag

## Example with 3 columns

**Sample data**

```
+----------------+--------+
|      User      |  Rep   |
+----------------+--------+
| Jon Skeet      | 854503 |
| Darin Dimitrov | 652133 |
| BalusC         | 639753 |
| Hans Passant   | 616871 |
| Me             |   5640 |
+----------------+--------+
```

**jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="reputation" columnCount="3" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="185" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a88bd694-4f90-41fc-84d0-002b90b2d73e">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="User" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Rep" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="9e7b5f50-5795-4c95-a122-f14f2e3f9366"/>
                <box leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[User]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="85" height="20" uuid="4a6f0a2a-d9b5-4e74-a9e8-0f965336f2bf"/>
                <box leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Double"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Reputation]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="8ff583b9-88dc-4726-85e1-16d79de78095"/>
                <box leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{User}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0">
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="85" height="20" uuid="ebd33b2f-7297-41c2-9dc7-78ff472890c4"/>
                <box leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Rep}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Result**

[image: output]